# Unable to find nested tags in XML with Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm querying an rss feed and getting back some xml. It looks like this:

```
<channel>
  <item>
    <description><![CDATA[<h5>18 Jun 2013: Zambia 2013</h5>
      <p>Welcome Home! <br />Return to Cork Airport.</p>
      <p><img src="http://thedomain.ie/images/pic.JPG"  /></p>
                ]]>
    </description>
  </item>
</channel>
```

To get the description tag, I do:

```
$(data).find('item').each(function (index) {

    description = $(this).find('description');
    console.log('description is ');
    console.log(description);

});
```

This works fine and I can see in the chrome concole the description tag is found. However, when I try to get any nested tags, it never finds them. For example, to find the image tag, I do:

```
img = $(this).find('description img');
```

But the image tag is never found. The same is true for the

tag. What am I doig wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `description` tag contains a CDATA block which is meant to hide data from the parser, so it is not parsed as HTML. You can get the content as text using:

```
var descriptionAsText = $(this).find('description').text();
```

And if you want to traverse the content as HTML, convert to a jQuery object as:

```
$(descriptionAsText).find('img')
```